# Xcode interface builder auto layout vertical spacing

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

When I select two components in interface builder and specify a vertical spacing autolayout constraint between them, how do I control whether it's the top space from one to the other or the bottom space? This value seems to be arbitrarily chosen for a given set of components and selecting one or the other first has no effect in changing this.

Comment: Assuming one component is higher than the other, Interface Builder uses the NSLayoutAttributeBottom of the higher component and the NSLayoutAttributeTop of the lower component. What constraint are you trying to make?

Comment: What I found was that if you added in a new component above or below a particular component directly within the document it would add a whole raft of unwanted constraints. I was therefore attempting to add the new component to the component tree and then set up the constraints from there. It was at this point that I discovered that the spacing constraints lacked the control to specify which way round components should relate to one another. I've since reverted back to defining auto layout constraints in code giving me full control. I'd recommend this approach to anyone developing complex UI's.

Answer (score 0):

To have some **more constraint options** in Interface Builder (Xcode 5) for constraints between view objects:

Instead of ctrl-dragging from the one view object to the other on the canvas ctrl-drag from the one view to the other in the **Document Outline**. That opens up constraint options like *Top*, *Center Y*, *Baseline*, and *Bottom*

[image: Constraint options in the Document Outline]
Constraint options in the **Document Outline**

vs.

[image: Constraint options on the Canvas]

Constraint options on the **Canvas**